# css calculate width based on classes applied to an element

Tags: css

Is there a way I can create some sort of CSS logic that can read the CSS class applied to an element and calculate new width?

Lets say I have an div element width the class "grid_6" - which is 480px in width.
Then I add a couple of other classes like; pl8 and pr16 - which is 8px padding on the left side, and 16px padding on the right side.

Is there any engine out the that could read these rules, then do something like : grid_6 - (p8+p16) and then set the new width of the element to, in this case, 456px to keep the total width at 480px?

I've looked at CSS calc(), but couldn't figure out how to make something like I'm trying to do...
Using PHP is of course a solution, but then it would be inline css, which is bad practice...

I know I can just have a child element and set the padding/margin/border on them to make sure I'm noot exceeding the total width. But was hoping for a smarter solution...

Anyone know of any?

Comment: Have you considered `box-sizing: border-box`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use `box-sizing`

Scott Cranfill gave this as a "solution" in a comment, but I am uncertain why he did not post it as a solution. The [`box-sizing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) changes how width calculations are done. So simply having this added:

```
.grid_6 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or more generically for all grid elements:

```
[class^=grid] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
}
```

Let's you add `padding` by other classes and not affect `width` [as this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/GxtLZ/3/). No complicated calculations needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SASS: http://sass-lang.com/

It allows you to do calculations and support for variables for CSS rules.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using LESS... Read a bit about it, but didn't get how it could be done...